# I want to export data of my script into 2 text files simultaneously using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

I have a power shell script that keeps running and I already export the output of this script into a notepad file and I always append it to keep updating itself.

Now, I want the output to 2 plain-text files.
1 which would have my appended output, and 2 which has only the latest data.

**How can I export the same output to 2 text files at same time?
Below is a snippet of my script.**

```
$(
write-host 'Checking Status.........'
GC .\file.txt | %{.\Status.ps1 $_}
) *>&1 > WINRMStatus.txt -Append
```

Comment: take a look at `Tee-Object` for one way to do that. then look at `-PipelineVariable` & `-OutVariable` in the `about_CommonParameters` help doc. finally, you can just save the new stuff to a $Var. then append it to one file and save it to a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine an appending redirection (`>>`) with [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Tee-Object):

```
& {
  write-host 'Checking Status.........'
  GC .\file.txt | %{.\Status.ps1 $_}
} *>&1 | Tee-Object OtherFile.txt >> WINRMStatus.txt
```

Also note that I've wrapped your statements in a *script block* (`{ ... }`) invoked with the call operator (`&`), which - unlike `$(...)`, the subexpression operator - preserves the streaming behavior of the enclosed commands (sends their output to the pipeline one by one instead of collecting everything in memory first).